# Is this expression for light coherence length correct?

Tags: optics, coherence

On the Wikipedia page for coherence length, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_length), the expression for the coherence length for a Gaussian source is

$L = \sqrt{ \frac{2 ln(2)}{n\pi}} \frac{\lambda^2}{\Delta \lambda}.$

In this expression the refractive index $n$ is under the square root. This seems odd to me, I would expect it to be

$L = \sqrt{ \frac{2 ln(2)}{\pi}} \frac{\lambda^2}{n\Delta \lambda}.$

I checked the source article but it doesn't explicitly mention the refractive index.

Is there something I'm missing or is this a mistake in the Wikipedia article?

Comment: The [cited source in the Wikipedia article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a90e/54af5f9669e04cc1000d7cdab68701bd762b.pdf) does not have refractive index in the expression for coherence length.

Comment: @Farcher, Yes, that is my issue with this article. If the refractive index were to be taken into account, where should it go?

Comment: I think you are right. Please go ahead and correct the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Ok, I corrected the Wikipedia article.